# NPM gives ELILIFECYCLE error when trying to run npm run build on linux

Tags: node.js, linux, reactjs, npm

I'm trying to build the project with `sudo npm run build` on linux but it give me this error:

```
ubuntu@ip:/var/www/reactcamera$ sudo npm run build

> youtubechannelvideos@0.1.0 build /var/www/reactcamera
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-qr-reader' in '/var/www/reactcamera/src'


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! youtubechannelvideos@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the youtubechannelvideos@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2018-02-23T19_07_23_567Z-debug.log
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "youtubechannelvideos",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "fetch": "^1.1.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1",
    "react-youtube": "^7.5.0",
    "dns": "file:./src/mock/dns",
    "react-qr-code": "0.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import YouTube from 'react-youtube';
import Fetch from 'fetch';
import QrReader from 'react-qr-reader';

class Test2 extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }
    render(){
        return (<RenderOnClick buttonName="Show Camera" element={<ShowPreview/>}/>);
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Test2/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: You should be doing everything in your power to not have to use `sudo` to do this.

Comment: Is there a way to give myself permissions so I don't have to write sudo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-qr-reader'
```

...

```
import QrReader from 'react-qr-reader';
```

run `npm install --save react-qr-reader` or `yarn add react-qr-reader`

you have `react-qr-code`, but not `react-qr-reader`

Comment: I did run npm install --save react-qr-reader. It gives me this:

react-qr-code@0.1.2 requires a peer of react-art-svg-renderer@^0.0.1-rc.8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

Comment: well, do what it says - install `react-art-svg-renderer` as well

Answer (score 0):

You should run an `npm install` first to make sure all dependencies are installed before building.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing the node_modules folder and reinstalling it, I was able to fix it simply by deleting the hidden node_modules/.cache folder!